# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS vs Ubuntu 14.04 LTS memory usage

Tags: ubuntu, memory

My droplet has 512 MB memory and is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bits and a Rails 4 application + several workers. It's running well.
I tried to deploy the same thing on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bits droplet and I've got plenty of memory related problem (can't fork).

Is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using way more RAM than Ubuntu 12.04 LTS? Is there something I should know to lower memory usage ? Should I stick with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does consumes more RAM, depending on your configuration too. For 512MB of RAM I recommend you to stay with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. If you upgrade your RAM then you will be also able to upgrade your OS to 14.04 LTS.

Ubuntu server 1.1. System Requirements:

- [Ubuntu 12.04 Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf)

If you are having trouble with RAM decreases I highly recommend you to do this:

- [How do I clean or disable the memory cache?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155768/how-do-i-clean-or-disable-the-memory-cache)